# High Resolution And ListView At Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winjs

I am working on a Windows 8 Metro App with HTML and JavaScript but i faced a problem with screen scaling.

Currently i am designing application for 1366x768. Generally there is a ListView on pages, you can see simple sketch for this resolution.
[image: 1366x768]

But when resolution increase, for example for 2560x1440 resolution ListView seems like image below.
[image: 2560x1440]

As you can see this seems very ugly.
Actually i am not sure what i should do for high resolutions.

First thing i thought preserve same ListView at 1366x768 resolution in the middle of screen.
But i couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to manage the layout. The first is to set the maximum number of rows that the `ListView` will display in its grid layout, like this:

```
list.winControl.layout.maxRows = 2;
```

If you have enough items, then this will have the effect of creating a wide, but shallow, layout.

You other option, the one you mention in your question, would be to centre the ListView and fix its size. I find that the easiest way to do this is to use the CSS flex box layout. Here is a little self-contained example that shows you both the `maxRows` setting and the CSS, which is applied to the element which contains the `ListView` (and not the ListView itself). Create a new VS project, copy the markup into the `default.html` file and start the app and you will be able to see the effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #list {
            width: 1366px; height: 768px;
        }
        .templateItem {
            width: 200px; height: 200px; font-size: 30pt;
            margin: 10px; border: thick solid white; background-color: gray;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        WinJS.Application.onactivated = function (args) {
            data = new WinJS.Binding.List();
            WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    data.push({ value: i });
                }
                list.winControl.layout.maxRows = 2;
            });
        }
        WinJS.Application.start();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="template" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
        <div class="templateItem" data-win-bind="innerText: value"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="list" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{
            itemDataSource: data.dataSource,
            itemTemplate:template}">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is hard to tell from your question, but you might also consider dropping the `ListView` and using something else. If you have a fixed number of items to display, you might want to use standard HTML element and use CSS (possibly using the new grid layout) to get more control over how they are displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After i asked it, i set height property to 768px outer div of ListView and it helped me. But first i looked for maxRows property but i couldn't find. So thanks for this, too ;)